# How load Static Files in Models Admin File from Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-web-services, static

I have my Django static files in Amazon Servers, and I trying to load these files in my Model Admin File, but its only work with absolute URLs.

In my Django templates I load and call my static files with

```
{% load admin_static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/myfile.js" %}"></script>
```

in settings.py i set this

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.mydomain.com/static/'
```

and in my Model Admin, in moment, it only works with

```
class Media:
    js = ("https://s3.mydomain.com/static/myfile.js",
          "https://s3.mydomain.com/static/myfile2.js",)
```

How can I load these files only with the static file name?
I trying

```
class Media:
    js = ("{% static "js/myfile.js" %}",
          "{% static "js/myfile2.js" %}",)
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

In your settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = "https://aws.domain.com/"
```

It is [standard settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#static-url). **Note**, that it must end in a slash if set to a non-empty value.

```
from django.conf import settings

class Media:
    js = (settings.STATIC_URL + "js/myfile.js",
          settings.STATIC_URL + "js/myfile2.js")
```